# string hashing with php

Tags: php, hashcode

I want to hash some utf-8 strings and store them in a databse, But is there a way to get the same value when hashing so lets say that blabla after hashing will be #dqr%36c and when I hash blabla again I should get the same value. I don't want to use salt. For some reasons in my database.
Here is the code

```
 $hashQuestion = md5($question);
 $hashAnswer = md5($answer);
 $sql = "UPDATE $table SET question='$question',   answer='$answer', hQuestion='$hashQuestion', hAnswer='$hashAnswer' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Other page

```
$q = md5($question);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fullQ)) {
printf(nl2br("\n%s\n"), $row['hQuestion']); 
}
```

Comment: If you do not use a salt the common hash functions will return the same result for the same input (and even with a salt: same salt->same input->same result).

Comment: It doesn't I've checked it with `hash` `md5` `crypt` and all give me different value

Comment: It doesn't look like you have tried it yet, try it first, then if there is an error come back and ask about that.

Comment: Post the code you are using.

Comment: `$hashQuestion = md5($question);
$hashAnswer = md5($answer);
$sql = "UPDATE $table SET question='$question', answer='$answer', hQuestion='$hashQuestion', hAnswer='$hashAnswer' WHERE id='$id'";`
  Then when I look for it `$q = md5($question);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fullQ)) {
printf(nl2br("\n%s\n"), $row['hQuestion']);
}` And they aren't equal

Comment: @AhmedNezar - could you edit your question and include your code in there? It's unreadable as a comment

Comment: @AhmedNezar - could you also add some of the sample data you're using? And what is your database structure?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by storing the hash anyway? What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: I'll store the hashed data into another field and then I'll hash the entered data and then I'll select the value of another field where the hashed data equal to the hashed input

Answer (score 0):

NO.

You cannot solve your [encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184994/database-sometimes-stores-arabic-sometimes-doesnt) by hashing some data and then "re-hashing" it back to get the value.

Comment: No encoding problem for now, The only problem that I can't use SELECT with them